# How can I convert YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00 to YYYY/MM/DD in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm converting some date in milliseconds to date format as seen below:

```
var dateFrom = new Date(1312883657720); //dateFrom = 2011-08-09T12:57:01
```

Now I need the value of dateFrom(2011-08-09T12:57:01) in this format: 2011/08/09. I can't seem to find a date method to remove the time string, is there a workaround needed?

Comment: Take a look to `momentjs`:  https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one

```
<div id="res">res</div>

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('/');
}
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML =  formatDate('2011-08-09T12:57:01') ;
```

Output: 2011/08/09

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

or another method is using calender,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
dateWithoutTime = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to form a string using the object

```
var dateFrom = new Date(1312883657720); //dateFrom = 2011-08-09T12:57:01
var humanDate = dateFrom.getFullYear()
                + "/" + ("0" + (dateFrom.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
                + "/" + ("0" + dateFrom.getDate()).slice(-2);

// ("0" + dateFrom.method()).slice(-2) is used to add the leading zero

console.log(humanDate); // 2011/08/09
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below two approaches

```
var newDate = moment(new Date(1312883657720)).format(YYYY/MM/DD);
```

or

```
var newDate = new Date(1312883657720);
newDate = newDate.getFullYear()+'/'+newDate.getMonth()+'/'+newDate getDate()
```